# How to find the width of a String (in pixels) in WIN32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Can you measure the width of a string more exactly in WIN32 than using the GetTextMetrics function and using tmAveCharWidth*strSize?

Comment: You should note that "tmAveCharWidth*strSize" is only sane for fixed width fonts.

Comment: Even for a decidedly fixed-width font (Iosevka), `tmAveCharWidth` does not match `tmMaxCharWidth` although I am not entirely sure what it would mean in practice nor do I have the code at hand to tell you if, say, the second number is some integer-multiple of the first (suggesting e.g. a grapheme spanning multiple glyph "boxes").

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938(VS.85).aspx).  That uses the current font for the given device context to measure the width and height of the rendered string in logical units.  For the default mapping mode, MM_TEXT, 1 logical unit is 1 pixel.

However, if you've changed the mapping mode for the current device context, a logical unit may not be the same as a pixel.  You can read about the different [mapping modes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  With the mapping mode, you can convert the dimensions returned to you by GetTextExtentPoint32 to pixels.

Comment: GetTextExtentPoint32 uses "logical units"; not pixels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @user good catch.  When the mapping mode is MM_TEXT (the default), 1 logical unit = 1 pixel, but that doesn't necessarily have to be true.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: And, nowadays, you also have to worry about high DPI scaling if your process is not marked as high-DPI aware.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know for certain, but it seems that:

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
RECT r = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
char str[] = "Whatever";
DrawText(hDC, str, strlen(str), &r, DT_CALCRECT);
```

might work.

Comment: Thanks, tried it and shows same width as GetTextExtentPoint32 :).

Comment: This is a much better solution than `GetTextExtentPoint32` since it takes the mapping mode out of equation. One thing the author needs to change is the flags for `DrawText`. Set it to `DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE`. The resulting width can be then calculated as `abs(r.right - r.left);`

Answer (score 5):

[Graphics::MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535787%28VS.85%29.aspx) ?

> ```
> VOID Example_MeasureString(HDC hdc)
> {
>    Graphics graphics(hdc);
>    // Set up the string.
>    WCHAR string[] = L"Measure Text";
>    Font font(L"Arial", 16);
>    RectF layoutRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
>    RectF boundRect;
>    // Measure the string.
>    graphics.MeasureString(string, 12, &font, layoutRect, &boundRect);
>    // Draw a rectangle that represents the size of the string.
>    graphics.DrawRectangle(&Pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0)), boundRect);
> }
> ```

Comment: Your method is definitely better than using GetTextExtentPoint32().

Comment: I have a confused thing. what is the layoutRect? I don't understand it

Comment: Instead of `RectF layoutRect(0, 0, 100, 50);` you can use `PointF pointF(0.0f, 0.0f);` for  `x` and `y`. See the example from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795957/c-gettextextentpoint32-doesnt-give-the-correct-size/66797699?noredirect=1#comment118098332_66797699

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are using this, you can use DrawText with DT_CALCRECT specified and it will (its always done it fairly accurately for me) calculate the size of the required rectangle based on the text/font/etc.

Answer (score 0):

For Builder C++ first make new TLabel dynamicly and then change font attributes.Set your TLabel as autosize.Then you can get you TLabel width witch represents your string width in pixels.

```
 int WidthPixels (String font, int size, String text)
 {
    TLabel* label = new TLabel(Form1); // dynamic TLabel
    label->AutoSize = true;
    label->Font->Name = font; // your font
    label->Font->Size = size; // your font size
    label->Caption = text; // your string
    return label->Width;
 }

int width = WidthPixels("Times New Roman", 19 , "Hey");
```