# Resize Controls Dynamically Based on Text

Tags: c++, windows

Using C++ and Windows, I want to resize a Button Width based on the Content.

For example if button text is "OK", then the width of button becomes let say 10 and if the content is "Cancel", then the width becomes 20. I know how to resize the control but I am not able to calculate how much we need to resize.

Any idea, How can we do that ?

Thanks

-Pankaj

Comment: Looks pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126730/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-string-in-pixels-in-win32

Comment: @chris: That's half of the solution, but indeed the hardest half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get dimensions of the text and then use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to resize the control.

Hope this will help and solves your problem...