# How to get the width of a string in pixels(/logical units)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, string, winapi

I am following a tutorial [here](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol2/9812/Horizontal_scrollbars_for_list_boxes.htm?PHPSESSID=2775c11e536d4d59932f81702a0847db), to add a horizontal scrollbar to a list control. Everything there works except the TextWidth() function (VC++ 2012 says it's undefined) so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126730/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-string-in-pixels-in-win32) question. But I have no idea how to initialize a hdc, so I tried [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/e5ea7702-de64-4919-9524-c2ef7c529540/). But GetTextExtentPoint32 keeps returning zero.

Any idea how I can solve this?

My code looks like this (after edit):

```
SIZE Size;
HDC hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
iResult=GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, szMessage, MESSAGE_SIZE, &Size);
```

(szMessage contains user input)

Comment: A string only has a defined width when you set it in a specific font.  That's why you need a graphics context (hdc).  Use the hdc for your output window.

Comment: @stark How do I get the hdc for my output window, that's where I'm stuck

Comment: You can get it by calling `GetDC(hWnd)`.

Comment: You should use `SIZE size;` and pass pointer to `GetTextExtentPoint32(..., &size)`;

Comment: @Slava works, thank you. Go ahead and post an answer if you want

Comment: Zero means success, to get width & height use `size.cx` & `size.cy`.

Comment: @Slava If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
If the function fails, the return value is zero. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so to answer my question:
The code above (see question) gives a way too high value for Size.cx because MESSAGE_SIZE is 1000 and not the size of the actual string so I used strMessage.c_str and strMessage.size() instead. This still gave some small inaccuracies with the output, I assumed this was because the wrong font was used, so I manually made a font. Now it gives a correct value for Size.cx. The code now looks like this:

```
int iHorExt=0;
SIZE Size;
int iCurHorExt=0 // iCurHorExt is actually a global var to prevent it from being reset to 0 evertime the code executes
string strMessage="Random user input here!"

HDC hdc=GetDC(hDlg);

//Random font
HFONT hFont=CreateFont(15, 5, NULL, NULL, FW_MEDIUM, false, false, false, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, FF_ROMAN, "Times New Roman");

//change font of the control
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, true);


SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

int iResult=GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, strMessage.c_str(), strMessage.size(), &Size);
if(iResult!=0)
{
    iHorExt=Size.cx;
    if(iHorExt>iCurHorExt)
    {
        iCurHorExt=iHorExt;
    }
}
```

later in the code:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, iCurHorExt, NULL);
```

Edit:

```
SelectObject(hdc, (HFONT)SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, WM_GETFONT, NULL, NULL));
```

Works too and doesn't require you to make a font or edit the font of the control

Answer (score 4):

My way:

```
SIZE sz;
HFONT font = GetFont();     //GetFont() is part of WTL. If using raw WinAPI it needs to get font in other means.
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
SelectObject(hdc, font);    //attach font to hdc

GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, text, lstrlenW(text), &sz);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```