# Winapi get string width in pixels

Tags: c++, winapi, type-conversion, gdi

I'm trying to create a method that gives me the width of a string in pixels.
My code so far:

```
inline void getTextWidth(HWND hwnd char* text) {
    SIZE textSize;
    GetTextExtentPoint32(GetDC(hwnd), text, strlen(text), &textSize);
    return ?;
}
```

I know that I should use `LPtoDP` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but at wants points as parameters and not the SIZE that GetTextExtentPoint32 returns.

How do I convert this?

Comment: This is pretty unclear.  Your question title says pixels, your body says points.  You are trying to get a function that returns void to return something.  You talk about parameters when you appear to mean return value.   Sloppy, make it better.  And explain why you think you need to change the mapping mode on a device context you created from scratch.

Comment: And don't forget to fix the `HDC` leak, too. The `HDC` returned by `GetDC()` needs to be freed with `ReleaseDC()` when you are done using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the width of a String (in pixels) in WIN32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126730/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-string-in-pixels-in-win32)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SIZE` structure contains both a height and a width. Since you only care about the width, you apparently want `LPtoDP(textSize.cx);`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using another method. For everyone who is interested, this is my solution:

```
int getStringWidth(char *text, HFONT font) {
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(dc, font);

    RECT rect = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    DrawText(dc, text, strlen(text), &rect, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);
    int textWidth = abs(rect.right - rect.left);

    DeleteDC(dc);
    return textWidth;
}
```

Comment: You match `ReleaseDC` with `GetDC`, ***not*** `DeleteDC`.

Comment: So, `ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);` ?