# how to find the width of fixed pitch font

Tags: winapi

I call `GetTextMetrics` on a fixed width font (Consolas).

I expected to see `tmAveCharWidth == tmMaxCharWidth` but no, they have different values. So which is the correct one?

I know I could just guess and use the one that seems correct, but that's not really a good plan given that I might get different results if I choose other fonts.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code in the form of a [mre]?

Comment: Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/string-widths-and-heights

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126730/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-string-in-pixels-in-win32 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222825/winapi-get-string-width-in-pixels

Comment: @JonathanPorter - that would not explain the difference 9..19

Comment: @KenWhite the dupe says its caused by cleartype. Not sure what that means or how it helps. Cannot show my code becuase this is now closed - sigh

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thats telling me to do what I am doing.

Comment: anyway - I just used ave width and its fine

Comment: ClearType is the Windows functionaltiy that tries to smooth fonts to remove the pixelation on curves on higher resolution screens. Google ClearType.

Comment: You have to take into account that CJK (Chinese, Japanese and Korean)  graphic characters can be classed into fullwidth and halfwidth characters with differing widths. Emoji are also known for using nonstandard widths even for fixed pitch fonts. Treating all fonts as proportional (by measuring widths with API calls) solves most of the problems, unless you are forced to work with fixed grid of characters.

Comment: @DanielSęk I am working with a fixed grid