# Can DT_CALCRECT format of DrawText() return the width?

Tags: c++, winapi, rect, drawtext

Hi I'm trying to know the required width value for a text to fit a `RECT`.

So for now I'm trying to get the `RECT` dimensions according to a `LPCWSTR`, using the `DT_CALCRECT` format of `DrawText()`.

[Microsoft states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext#syntax) that `DT_CALCRECT`

> Determines the width and height of the rectangle. [...] DrawText returns the height of the formatted text[...]

The following code

```
LPCWSTR textCheck = L"12345";
RECT rectCheck = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int check = DrawText(
    hdc,
    textCheck,
    -1,
    &rectCheck,
    DT_CALCRECT);
```

returns the same value (16), `textCheck` being "12345" and "123456789".

Is it able to return only the height or I'm missing something?

Is `DT_CALCRECT` able to determines the width for itself but can't return it?

I expected `DT_CALCRECT` able to return the width and the height.

Comment: I'm thinking about looking if `DrawText()` can draw vertically lol!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't see what other relevant information I could add to the question, if you do please tell.

Comment: So your 1st comment wasn't meant as additional information?

Comment: Just read the documentation again, it is pretty clear. Pay attention to `[in, out] LPRECT  lprc,` and the comment on the return value (you don't use DT_VCENTER or DT_BOTTOM so it should be 0 all the time). So after you call the function `lprc` should contain the rectangle

Comment: I assume you know what an in/out parameter is?

Comment: The value "16" that it returns... is that the width or the height? I assume you're saying that it always returns the same width and the same height, even though the length of the string increases (and thus you would expect a larger width to be returned)? This functionality *does* work; I've used it many times. DrawText *can* draw text vertically, but you need to create a font with the escapement set to 900.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I meant I could try to draw the text vertically to get the width using the height but I guess that is not serious... ^^

Comment: @PepijnKramer I saw these `[in]` / `[in, out]` written in the documentations few times but it seems I ignored it. I'm now trying to learn how to use this to get the "returned" rectangle as you said.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike I think the value "16" that it returns is the height, I am trying to get the width too. Thank you very much for the info about the font escapement!

Comment: Details matter ;) Also try some of the flag combinations so you get more of a feel of what the documentation is trying to tell you

Comment: This is all covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtextw) for the DrawText function. *If the function succeeds, the return value is the height of the text in logical units*. `DT_CALCRECT` is similarly described in detail. Stack Overflow should not be your first port of call when something doesn't work - always start by reading the API documentation.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I agree I don't read enough the documentations. But I try a lot imo before posting on Stack Overflow (I search on Google and ask chatgpt). I think I use Stack Overflow when I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, if you just want the width needed to render a string (on a single line), combo DT_CALCRECT with DT_SINGLELINE and then inspect the `rectCheck` which is an out param.

```
LPCWSTR textCheck = L"12345";
RECT rectCheck = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int check = DrawText(
    hdc,
    textCheck ,
    -1,
    &rectCheck ,
    DT_CALCRECT|DT_SINGLELINE);

int requiredWidth = rectCheck.right-rechCheck.left;
```

Comment: I would have used [GetTextExtentPoint32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextextentpoint32w) instead: "*The GetTextExtentPoint32 function computes the width and height of the specified string of text.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've read a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126753/22157294) saying that using `DrawText()` "is a much better solution than `GetTextExtentPoint32` since it takes the mapping mode out of equation.", what do you think about it?

Comment: I am starting to use `GetTextExtentPoint32` because the width of `DT_CALCRECT` was not the same when building as x86 and as x64.

Comment: @Raphael - I'd love to see a [MCVE] of that. Are you sure the difference isn't from some change in dpi awareness between processes?

Comment: @selbie Can you suggest me a way to show you this minimal reproducible example? I don't know how to send it to you. I don't know about the dpi awarness but I think I tried `SetProcessDPIAware` before switching to `GetTextExtentPoint32`.

Comment: @selbie I can't reproduce the difference anymore, I guess I thought it returned a difference because when building as x86, the child window background expanded to the parent's right bound, but when building as x64, the background just took the text width. I tested multiple times and just changing the architecture made this background width difference, but my code was a mess, it didn't even behave the same each Run without changing architecture. If I figure out what was causing this I will send you a comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetTextExtentPoint32 to return a tuple (width,rect) of the formatted text

Eg this code in python:

```
wText, hText = win32gui.GetTextExtentPoint32(handleDC,strText)
```